# Supremum of a bounded set of real-valued functions in $L^\infty(X)$

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory, operator-algebras, measurable-functions, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and consider the algebra $L^\infty(X)$. The real-valued functions carry a canonical order, where $g\leq f$ if $g(x)\leq f(x)$ a.e. The following result holds:

> Let $B\subset L^\infty(X)$ be a  set of real valued functions which is bounded (that is, there exists $c>0$ with $\|f\|_\infty\leq c$ for all $f\in B$). Then $B$ admits a least upper bound $g$ in $L^\infty(X)$.

As far as I can tell, the straightforward argument that one first thinks about does not work; because one would attempt to take the pointwise supremum, which of course will be bounded but there is no obvious reason why it has to be measurable. Moreover, taking the pointwise supremum raises the issue of dealing with possibly uncountably many nullsets, which kind of puts the argument away from usual measure theory.

The reason I know the result is true is the following. For any $F\subset B$ finite, we can define $g_F=\max\{f:\ f\in F\}$. Because we are dealing with finitely many functions, $g_F\in L^\infty(X)$ and $f\leq g_F$ a.e. for all $f\in F$. Now the net $\{g_F\}_{F\in B}$ is a monotone increasing bounded net of real-valued functions. Here is where I need to appeal to higher level stuff: since $L^\infty(X)$ is a von Neumann algebra, any bounded monotone increasing net of selfadjoint elements admits a least upper bound.  So there exists $g\in L^\infty(X)$ that is the least upper bound of $\{g_F\}_{F\in B}$. The reason $g$ is a least upper bound for $B$ is that if $h$ is an upper bound for $B$, then $g_F\leq h$ for all $F$, and then $g\leq h$.

And now we get to the question: **is it possible to prove the existence of the least upper bound for $B$, with measure theory arguments?**

The proof using von Neumann algebra ideas is not crazy hard, but it uses non-trivial results. Basically one represents $L^\infty(X)$ faithfully on $B(\ell^2(X))$ acting by left multiplication, that is $\pi(f)\eta=f\,\eta$, and considers the numerical nets $\{\langle \pi(g_F)\xi,\xi\rangle\}$ for each $\xi\in \ell^2(X)$. As these are bounded monotone nets in $\mathbb R$, they converge. This way one gets numbers $\{\langle T\xi,\xi\rangle\}$ and it is standard Hilbert space theory using polarization that this defines an operator $T\in B(\ell^2(X))$. The operator $T$ is a weak-operator limit of elements of $\pi(L^\infty(X))$, which is a von Neumann algebra, and so $T\in \pi(L^\infty(X))$, which means that there exists $g\in L^\infty(X)$ with $\pi(g)=T$.

It would be nice to have instead a proof intrinsic to $L^\infty(X)$.

Comment: What is wrong with taking a constant function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What would you do with a constant function?

Comment: Nevermind, I miss the part of _least_ upper bound.

Comment: For complete Radon measures, there is in Bourbaki Integration I (ch.4, par 3, no.6) relatively small proof that $L^p$ is fully complete lattice for any $1 \le p \le \infty.$  It relies on the facts that the limit of increasing net is actually a least upper bound and $L^p$ are complete. For longer story about order in topological vector spaces, one may check Schaefer's Topological vector spaces.

Comment: The order in the von Neumann algebra $L^\infty(X)$ may be not the same as that in the function space  $L^\infty(X)$.

Comment: @C.Ding: what do you mean? The canonical way to see $L^\infty(X)$ as a von Neumann algebra is as left multiplication operators on $L^2(X)$. In that context, $M_f\geq0$ if and only if $f\geq0$ a.e., which gives the order I mentioned.

Comment: @MartinArgerami If the measure is not $\sigma$-finite, why does $M_f\geq 0$ imply that $f\geq 0$ a.e.?

Comment: This is how I would do it. $M_f\geq0$ means that $\langle M_fg,g\rangle\geq0$ for all $g\in L^2$, which is 
$$\tag1
\int_Xf\,|g|^2\,d\mu\geq0. 
$$
Let $E=\{f<0\}$. If $\mu(E)>0$, then by continuity of the measure there exists $n$ such that $\mu(E_n)>0$, where $E_n=\{f<-\frac1n\}$. Put $g=1_E$. Then $(1)$ gives 
$$
0\leq \int_Xf\,1_E\,d\mu=\int_Ef\,d\mu\leq-\frac1n\,\mu(E_n),
$$
a contradiction. The contradiction happens even if $\mu(E_n)=\infty$. Am I using that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @MartinArgerami You are correct. So, the expalnation for why both your arguemts and my counter example hold is that $L^\infty(X)$ may fail to be a von Neumann algebra, as you find out.

Comment: Indeed. This was nice.

Comment: @C.Ding, could you please explain? I am confused. If you consider $L^\infty$ as a space of functions (not space of equivalence classes of functions) then $\le$ is not an order i.e antireflexivity does not hold. If one considers $L^\infty$ as a space of equivalence classes then Schaefer/Wolff "Topological vector spaces"  p.286 claims that $L^\infty(\mu)$ are exactly commutative v.Neumann algebras where $\mu$ is a Borel measure on locally compact space. And, surely, $\sup$ in $L^\infty$ as a set of equivalence classes does not equal to pointwise supremum.

Comment: @dsh By "function space", I mean exactly the space of equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: @C.Ding And you consider classes of equivalences of measurable function (or classes of all functions)? Thank you.

Comment: @dsh Measurable functions, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a counter example if you do not assume that the measure space is $\sigma$-finite.
Let $X$ be an uncountable set, $\mu$ a counting measure, and $\Sigma$ the family of set $A$ such that $A$ or the complement of $A$ is countable.
Consider that $S$ is a subset of $X$ such that both itself and its complement are uncountable, then $B: =\{\chi_A|A \mbox{ is a countable subset of }S\}$ has no least upper bound.

If you assume that the measure space is $\sigma$-finite, then the result you quote is true. Define $B^\vee:=\{\sup A| A\mbox{ is a finite subset of } B\}$, then $B^\vee$ is also bounded above. The key point is that the supremum $\alpha$ of *integrals* of elements in $B^\vee$ exists when $\mu$ is a finite measure, so we can find a sequence $(f_n)$ in $B^\vee$ such that $\int f_n$ converges to $\alpha$. Moreover,  we may assume that $(f_n)$ is increasing by replacing $f_n$  with $f_1\vee f_2\vee\cdots\vee f_n$. Let $g$ be the supremum of the sequence $f_n$, then $g$ is the least upper bound of $B$. Indeed, for any $f\in B$,
\begin{align*}
\alpha \geq \int (f_n\vee f)\geq \int f_n,
\end{align*}
which follows that $\int (f_n\vee f)$ converges to $\alpha$. By Monotone Convergence Theorem, $\int (g\vee f)-\int g=\alpha-\alpha=0$.  This implies that $g\vee f-g$ is the zero element in $L^\infty(X)$, i.e., $f\leq g$.

Comment: What is $\mu$ exactly? One usually allows a measure to take a single infinite value, not different cardinalities. The typical measure for your $\Sigma$ is $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ countable and $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $A$ uncountable, and in that case your $\chi_A=0$ for all countable $A$. (by the way, the proof you provided is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for, as it is the exact same idea I used for von Neumann algebras but constrained to pure measure theory arguments)

Comment: @MartinArgerami $\mu(A)$ is the cardinality of $A$, not the  typical measure.

Comment: Ok, that's not what I call a "measure space", then. I need to think what survives and what doesn't if one allows $\mu$ to take different infinite values.

Comment: @MartinArgerami To clarify, $\mu(A)$ always take the value $\infty$ if $A$ is infinite.

Comment: I see. Not the most interesting measure if it only takes the value $\infty$. I'm noticing that I have completely forgotten the role of $\sigma$-finiteness in $L^\infty(X)$; I'm not even sure if it is a von Neumann algebra for a non $\sigma$-finite measure. Come to think about it, your example shows that $L^\infty(X)$ may fail to be a von Neumann algebra when the measure is not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: On reading your argument a bit more carefully, I think you need to define $\alpha$ as the supremum over all finite joins of functions in $B$. Otherwise you could have something like $B=\{1_{[0,1]},1_{[1,2]}\}$, and then $\alpha=1$ while $\int(f_1\vee f_2)=2$. (there's also a couple typos in the last two sentences).

Comment: @MartinArgerami In fact, I need to  define $\alpha$ as the supremum over all **countable** joins of functions in $B$, because it has to contain the $g$ in my answer. Corrected now.

Comment: I think if you define it over finite joins you get that $\int f\vee g=\alpha$ for any $f\in B$ by using Monotone Convergence. Also you have typos near the end, since $f_n\vee g=g$ and it is not what you need.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Yes, you are correct. My typo confused myself,  leading to my last comment. Finite joins is enough, as your arguemnts for vN algebra.

Comment: I corrected a few more typos near the end.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you. You are so clever that you can understand an answer  with typos on key information.

Comment: Your answer was very nice and enlightening.